# Searching for duplicates via matching patterns using T-SQL

Tags: sql-server-2014

I am trying to find duplicates within a column, where the data represents the same thing but has not been normalized correctly during processing. 
I have built a # table  with two key fields to search on.
Instead of trimming or manipulating the column I would like to bring back any matches > 8 characters in common sequentially.

Example data:

```
ID    Information
1     ABCDEF12.domain
2     domain.ABCDEF12
3     XYZABC123.22.26
4     222-XYZABC123-26
5     YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY
6     AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
7     XYZABC123
8     ABCDEF12
9     123456789.1.2
```

would return sorted by least in length:

```
ID    Information
8     ABCDEF12
1     ABCDEF12.domain
2     domain.ABCDEF12
7     XYZABC123
3     XYZABC123.22.26
4     222-XYZABC123-26
```

Any starting points, best practice or any pointers to achieve this would be great. I am unsure how to initially identify any values that have 8 characters or more in common initially to narrow the data set, the sort is relatively simple.

Comment: This is best handled with a scripting language outside of SQL Server. How did you remove rows 6 and 7? They are of equal length, but different characters where as rows 1 and 2 are the inverse of each other and most could argue they are more alike than the omitted rows. Can you try and elaborate on your logic a bit?

Comment: Hi  scsimon this is just a sample output i have stated.

Row 5 omitted as 8 character match does not occur more than once in the Information dataset
Row 6 omitted as 8 character match does not occur more than once in the Information dataset
Row 9 omitted as 8 character match does not occur more than once in the Information dataset

Remaining data can be sorted in various ways, as long as grouped together by the common pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one solution.
This uses [Alan Burstein's tally table Number function](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/scripts/Set+Based/139370/)

```
DECLARE @T1 TABLE ([ID] int, [Information] Nvarchar(16)) ;

INSERT INTO @T1 (ID ,Information)
VALUES
    (1, N'ABCDEF12.domain'),
    (2, N'domain.ABCDEF12'),
    (3, N'XYZABC123.22.26'),
    (4, N'222-XYZABC123-26'),
    (5, N'YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY'),
    (6, N'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA'),
    (7, N'XYZABC123'),
    (8, N'ABCDEF12'),
    (9, N'123456789.1.2')
;

SELECT DISTINCT 
    T.ID,T.Information
FROM @T1 T
CROSS APPLY dbo.getNums(1, LEN(T.Information), 1, 1) N
INNER JOIN
    @T1 T1  ON  (   SUBSTRING(T.Information, N, LEN(T.Information)) LIKE '%' + T1.Information + '%' OR
                    SUBSTRING(T1.Information, N, LEN(T1.Information)) LIKE '%' + T.Information + '%' 
                )
            AND (   LEN(SUBSTRING(T1.Information, N, LEN(T1.Information))) > 8                      OR 
                    LEN(SUBSTRING(T.Information, N, LEN(T.Information))) > 8 
                )
            AND T1.ID <> T.ID
```

Output

```
ID  Information
4   222-XYZABC123-26
8   ABCDEF12
1   ABCDEF12.domain
2   domain.ABCDEF12
7   XYZABC123
3   XYZABC123.22.26
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. I cannot get this working with the data provided on my test instance. I believe this is due to the cross apply of the function. When i call the function using the examples in the function itself it works fine. When i try your code i get:

Invalid column name 'N'.

Comment: Update the question with TSQL code causing the problem so I can see where the problem might be

Answer (score 0):

Replace `YOUR_TABLE` with your table name and try below:

```
SELECT A.Id, TBL.Information, TBL.Id as New_Id
INTO #FINAL
FROM YOUR_TABLE as A
OUTER APPLY
            ( 
              SELECT Information, ID FROM YOUR_TABLE as B WHERE Information LIKE (SELECT '%' + Information + '%' FROM YOUR_TABLE as C WHERE  C.ID = A.ID)
            ) TBL


SELECT Information FROM #FINAL WHERE Id In (SELECT Id from #FINAL GROUP BY Id HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)
```